# traceroute have error bind: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: linux, networking, bind, openstack, traceroute

I have the below error:

```
[root@~]# traceroute -s 'publicIP' 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
**bind: Cannot assign requested address**
```

But when i did not enter source, it works fine:

```
[root@pf-apispens ~]# traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.111.1 (192.168.111.1)  1.759 ms  1.728 ms  1.649 ms
 2  * * *
 3  172.24.7.x (172.24.7.x) 1.752 ms  1.744 ms  1.816 ms
 4  61.8.x.x (61.8.x.x)  1.635 ms  1.653 ms  1.632 ms

[root@~]# ip addr
{1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1454 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:a7:5c:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.111.xyz/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.111.xyzz/32 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fea7:5cd0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fa:16:3e:1d:e7:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[root@~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.111.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
172.27.0.0      192.168.111.2   255.255.254.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.111.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Please advice me on resolution.
Do let me know if you need more information.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type `traceroute -s` with addresses which directly assign to any interfaces on your server.

You can type any of this addresses from your output of `ip a`:

```
192.168.111.xyz
192.168.111.xyzz
```

But not real public ip because it has assigned to your other device (e.g. router).

See `man traceroute`:

> **-s source_addr, --source=source_addr**
>
> Chooses  an alternative source address. Note that you must select the address of one of the interfaces.  By default, the
>   address of the outgoing interface is used.

Comment: Thanks! let me test out and feedback :)
Very interesting to know.